# VB.NET EF - Creating a generic function that inspects an entity & permits entity save? Code First

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I know, this sounds strange... But this is what I'm trying to do, how far along I am, and why I'm even doing it in the first place:

1. The class is configured, as an instance, with the name of the class. The context class is also available for preparing the batch class.
2. Pass a generic list of objects (entities, really) to a class.
3. That class (which can be pre-configured for this particular class) does just one thing: Adds a new entity to the backend database via DBContext.
4. The same class can be used for any entity described in the Context class, but each instance of the class is for just one entity class.

I want to write a blog article on my blog showing the performance of dynamically adjusting the batch size when working with EF persistence, and how constantly looking for the optimum batch size can be done.

When I say "DBContext" class, I mean a class similar to this:

```
Public Class CarContext
        Inherits DbContext

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New("name=vASASysContext")
        End Sub

        Public Property Cars As DbSet(Of Car)

        Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(Of Car)(New CarConfiguration())
        End Sub

    End Class
```

That may sound confusing. Here is a use-case (sorta):

Need: I need to add a bunch of entities to a database. Let's call them cars, for lack of an easier example. Each entity is an instantiation of a car class, which is configured via Code First EF6 to be manipulated like any other class that is well defined in DBContext. Just like in real world classes, not all attributes are mapped to a database column.

High Level: 
-I throw all the entities into a generic list, the kind of list supported by our 'batch class'.
-I create an instance of our batch class, and configure it to know that it is going to be dealing with car entities. Perhaps I even pass the context class that has the line:
-Once the batch class is ready (may only need the dbcontext instance and the name of the entity), if is given the list of entities via a function something like:

```
Public Function AddToDatabase(TheList as List(Of T)) As Double
```

The idea is pretty simple. My batch class is set to add these cars to the database, and will add the cars in the list it was given. The same rules apply to adding the entities in batch as they do when adding via DBContext normally.

All I want to happen is that the batch class itself does not need to be customized for each entity type it would deal with. *Configuration* is fine, but not *customization*.

OK... But **WHY**?

Adding entities via a list is easy. The secret sauce is the batch class itself. I've already written all the logic that determines the rate at which the entities are added (in something akin to "Entities per Second). It also keeps track of the best performance, and varies the batch size occasionally to verify.

The reason the function above (called *AddToDatabase()* for illustrative purposes) returns a double is that the double represents the amount of entities that were added per second.

Ultimately, the batch class returns to the calling method the number of entities to put in the *next* batch to maintain peak performance.

So my question for you all is how I can determine the entity fields, and use that to save the entities in a given list.

Can it be as simple as copying the entities? Do I even need to use reflection at all, and have the class use 'GetType' to figure out the entity class in the list (cars)?

How would you go about this?

Thank yu very much in advance for your reading this far, and your thoughtful response..

---

[Don't read further unless you are into this kind of thing!]

The performance of a database operation isn't linear, and is dependent on several factors (memory, CPU load, DB connectivity, etc.), and the DB is not always on the same machine as the application. It may even involve web services.

Your first instinct is to say that more entities in a single batch is best, but that is probably not true in most cases. When you add entities to a batch add, at first you see an increase in performance (increase in entities/second). But as the batch size increases, the performance may reach a maximum, then start to decrease (for a lot of reasons, not excluding environmental, such as memory). For non-memory issues, the batch performance may start to level off, and we haven't even discussed the impact of the batch on the system itself.

So in the case of a leveling off, I don't want my batch size any larger than it needs to be to be in the *neighborhood* of peak performance. Also, with smaller batch sizes, the class is able to evaluate the system's performance more frequently.

Being new to Code First and EF6, I can see that there must be some way to use reflection to determine how to take the given list of entities, break them apart into the entity attributes, and persist them via the EF itself.

So far, I do it this way because I need to manually configure each parameter in the INSERT INTO...

```
For Each d In TheList
    s = "INSERT INTO BDTest (StartAddress, NumAddresses, LastAddress, Duration) VALUES (@StartAddress, @NumAddresses, @LastAddress, @Duration)"
    Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(s, conn)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartAddress", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = d.StartIP
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NumAddresses", Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = d.NumAddies
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastAddress", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = d.LastAddie
        singleRate = CDbl(Me.TicksPerSecond / swSingle.Elapsed.Ticks)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Duration", Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = singleRate
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()
    End Using
Next
```

I need to steer away in this test code from using SQL, and closer toward EF6...

What are your thoughts?

TIA!

Comment: I'm sorry... I'm actually a bit perplexed by this statement.  "...there must be some way to use reflection to determine how to take the given list of entities, break them apart into the entity attributes, and persist them..."  Do you know how EF actually works?  .SaveChanges() and all that?

Comment: You can accomplish batch saves via EF by using a TransactionScope in your save method and adding a given set of entities to the context and calling SaveChanges on that set.  Structure your loop to only add say 100 at a time, or however many you deem as optimal to save.

Comment: @AaronPalmer re: perplexed... I am far from an expert, but I started with Code First, and stuck with it. Your confusion might be from my saying that the batch class needs to know which configured entity it is dealing with. In thinking out loud, I figured I could either pass it something on instantiation, or pass it the DBcontext class and allow it to 'figure out' which entity class it had a list of, then appy the .SaveChanges() to that particular class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are two issues I see that you should tackle.  First is your question about creating a "generic" method to add a list of entities to the database.

```
Public Function AddToDatabase(TheList as List(Of T)) As Double
```

If you are using POCO entities, then I would suggest you create an abstract base class or interface for all entity classes to inherit from/implement.  I'll go with `IEntity`.

```
Public Interface IEntity
End Interface
```

So your `Car` class would be:

```
Public Class Car
Implements IEntity

    ' all your class properties here    

End Class
```

That would handle the generic issue.

The second issue is one of batch inserts.  A possible implementation of your method could be as follows.  This will insert a batches of 100, modify the paramater inputs as needed.  Also replace MyDbContext with the actual `Type` of your DbContext.

```
Public Function AddToDatabase(ByVal entities as List(Of IEntity)) As Double
    Using scope As New TransactionScope

        Dim context As MyDbContext
        Try
            context = new MyDbContext()
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false

            Dim count = 0
            For Each entityToInsert In entities
                count += 1
                context = AddToContext(context, entityToInsert, count, 100, true)
            Next

            context.SaveChanges()
        Finally
            If context IsNot Nothing
                context.Dispose()
            End If
        End Try

        scope.Complete()
    End Using

End Function

Private Function AddToContext(ByVal context As MyDbContext, ByVal entity As IEntity, ByVal count As Integer, ByVal commitCount As Integer, ByVal recreateContext as Boolean) As MyDbContext

    context.Set(entity.GetType).Add(entity)

    If (count % commitCount = 0)
        context.SaveChanges()
        If (recreateContext)
            context.Dispose()
            context = new MyDbContext()
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false
        End If
    End If

    return context
End Function
```

Also, please apologize if this is not 100% perfect as I mentally converted it from C# to VB.Net while typing.  It should be very close.

Comment: I like this approach a lot. I am traveling seemingly non-stop so have little time to test/adapt. One thing I did was clean out all the SQL, and use EF's _.AddRange_, which sped things up, but still I'm dealing with a custom written class (non-generic). I need to implement along the lines of what you posted above to give more/better feedback. Thank you for your considerate post! I can't wait to finish the next round so I'll have some code to show you all... Until then!